# Limit the array size 2D (C# UNITY)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Hello guys is it possible to limit the array size just like this example

[image]

Now i want only to show 6 of them.

What i have done so far is this

**CustomClass**

```
const int MAX = 104;  // = 8 decks * 52 cards / 4cardsoneround
const int Y = 6;

int[,] arrayRoad = new int[Y, X];

 public int[,] GetRoad(int x) {
    arrayRoad = new int[x, 6];
    return arrayRoad;
}
```

Now I'm displaying it on my **MainClass** like this

```
ScoreBoard bsb = new ScoreBoard();

private void Road()
{
    bsb.makeRoad(history); // Road
    int[,] arrayRoad = bsb.GetRoad(6); //<--- sample value 6

    string s = "";
    for (int y = 0; y < arrayRoad.GetLength(0); y++)
    {
        //just 27 for now
       
        for (int x = 0; x < 28; x++)
        {
            s += string.Format("{0:D2}",arrayRoad[y, x]);
            s += ".";
        }
        s += "\n";
    }
    Debug.Log(s);
}
```

The problem with this code is that it's giving me an `Array out of index`

Is this possible??

## Updated

```
public int[,] GetRoad(int x = MAX,int y = Y) {
    arrayRoad = new int[y, x];
   
    return arrayRoad;
}
```

Where in my `Max = 104` and `Y = 6`

```
int[,] arrayRoad = bsb.GetRoad(12,6); //12 rows and 6 in height

    string s = "";
    for (int y = 0; y < arrayRoad.GetLength(0); y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < arrayRoad.GetLength(1); x++)
        {
            s += string.Format("{0:D2}",arrayRoad[y, x]);
            s += ".";
        }
        s += "\n";
    }
    Debug.Log(s);
}
```

I have all this value earlier before i perform the update code

[image]

Now when i perform the updated code here's what I got

[image]

The expected result must be this

[image]

Inside of that black marker those twelve columns only must be shown because i declared on my

```
int[,] arrayRoad = bsb.GetRoad(12,6);
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Is it possible?

Comment: it's giving me an `Out of Range` error .

Comment: Is `arrayBigEyeRoad` the a typo of `arrayRoad` again?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues too much typo I am very sorry. geez

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: And where are you setting the values on the array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172471/discussion-between-theginxx009-and-rodrigo-rodrigues).

Comment: I am setting it on here `public int[,] GetRoad(int x = MAX,int y = Y) {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did here was copy my old array to the new one just like this code below

```
int[,] arrayBigRoadResult = new int[6, x];
//copy manually the element references inside array
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
    {
        arrayBigRoadResult[i, j] = arrayBigRoad[i, j];
    }
 }
return arrayBigRoadResult;
```

then by calling it just like this

```
int[,] arrayRoad = bsb.GetRoad(12);
```

It would only display 12 columns and 6 rows :)

Answer (score 2):

Note this:

```
 public int[,] GetBigEyeRoad(int x) {
    arrayRoad = new int[x, 6]; // <-------------
    return arrayBigEyeRoad;
```

There you are fixing the length of the second dimension of the array to 6.

```
    for (int x = 0; x < 28; x++)
    {
        s += string.Format("{0:D2}",arrayBigEyeRoad[y, x]); // <------------
```

There, you are trying to access indices up to 28 on the second dimension of the array. The `Out of Range` error comes from that.

Comment: please see my edit on what i did earlier before you post your answer

Comment: Check the final part of my answer: You are fixing the SECOND dimenision of your array into 6 inside the GetRoad method. Later, in the for loop, you are trying to iterate on the SECOND dimension with values higher than 6. That's the problem

Comment: actually fixed that but the problem now is that the values that i have on my 2D arrays are gone . Hmmmm .